# Self Hosted Fonts not working in Gatsby with Safari

Tags: css, gatsby

I have been googling and trying things for days on this but I am still struggling to get Safari to display a custom font (works OK in FF and Chrome) with styled components

This is in my globalstyles.js

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'
export default createGlobalStyle`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Langdon';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local(Langdon), 
    url('./fonts/langdon-webfont.ttf') format(truetype), 
    url('./fonts/langdon-webfont.woff') format(woff),
    url('./fonts/langdon-webfont.woff2') format(woff2);
  }
```

globalstyles.js is imported into my layout.js

Then I am using this in my component:

```
const RocketShipTitle = styled.h1`
  color: #cc9056;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-family: Langdon, sans-serif;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 100;
`
```

Any ideas anybody?

Thanks

Comment: Did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem—I was able to get it to work by importing fonts into an `index.js` file in `/fonts` and exporting, so in your case:

```
import LangdonWOFF "./fonts/langdon-webfont.woff"
import LangdonTTF "./fonts/langdon-webfont.ttf"

export { LangdonWOFF, LandonTTF }
```

then importing and using in `globalstyles.js`

```
import * as font from "./fonts"


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Langdon';
    src: url(${font.LangdonTTF}) format(truetype), 
    url(${font.LangdonWOFF}) format(woff);
}
```